# Remove duplicate key value pairs with tolerance by keeping the ones with largest value

Tags: arrays, matlab, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates with tolerance from a set of keys and values using the following rule:

Assume the following set:

```
keys = [1 2 3 3.1 3.15 4 5];
vals = [0.8 1 1.1 1.3 1.2 1 1.1];
```

Plotted this would look like this:
[image: Plotted key value pair]

Now I would like to remove those pairs where the keys are very close together as indicated in the plot by the red circle. The key value pair that I would like to keep is that one with the largest value (in the example the middle one `[3.1; 1.3]`), so that the resulting set would be:

```
keys = [1 2 3.1 4 5];
vals = [0.8 1 1.3 1 1.1];
```

I tried to use Matlab's `diff` function to get this behavior by doing

```
vals_new = keys(~(diff(keys) < 0.5));
keys_new = vals(~(diff(keys) < 0.5));
[M,I] = max(vals(diff(keys) < 0.5));
```

This gives vals_new and keys_new as a new set that only includes the last of the duplicate pairs, but is also lacking the very last value:

```
keys_new = [1 2 3.15 4]
vals_new = [0.8 1 1.2 1]
```

The last line returns the index of the maximum value of the duplicate pairs `I=2`, however does unfortunately not include the last of the three duplicate pairs `[3.15; 1.2]` so it's more a coincidence that it is correct here.

I feel like there should be a much smarter way to do this, but can't really get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

**Step1.** Find all the non-max point in the current keys&vals, which has a larger neighbor in front of it or just behind it, and build a Set called `Nind`.

**Step2.** Create another Set called `Cind`, which contains every point that has a close neighbor and needed to be considered in the current keys&vals.

**Step3.** Intersect `Nind` and `Cind`, and delete the same part in the `Keys` and `Vals`.

**Step4.** If the intersect of two set is empty, goto **Step5**. In the other cases, goto **Step1**.

**Step5.** This is the end~

Note that a while loop is dealing with some ugly input which has multiple max points, something like:

[image]

My code:

```
%% Input
clc; clear;
keys = [1 2 3 3.1 3.15 4 5];
vals = [0.8 1 1.1 1.3 1.2 1 1.1];


%% Dealing
ind=-1;
while(~isempty(ind))
  %find the non-max point
  Max=([diff(vals) 0]<0 & [0 -diff(vals)]<0); 
  Nind=1:length(vals);
  Nind(Max)=[];

  %determine the range of points
  Cind=[0 diff(keys)<0.5];
  Cind(find(Cind)-1)=1;
  vec=1:length(Cind);
  Cind=Cind.*vec;
  Cind(Cind == 0)=[];

  %check through & back
  ind=intersect(Cind,Nind);
  keys(ind)=[];
  vals(ind)=[];
end

%% Output
[keys;vals]
```

the output of the code is:

```
ans =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.1000    4.0000    5.0000
    0.8000    1.0000    1.3000    1.0000    1.1000
```

Comment: Hi Jiang, this works perfectly! I just changed one line to `Cind=[0 diff(keys)<0.5 & abs(diff(keys)>0.01)];` because I also had to get rid of "real" duplicates. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's okay, glad that I could help~ @Axel

Comment: Hey Jiang, I encountered some problems when I tried to use your solution on a different set. I put those problems into a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288027/removing-repetitions-removes-too-many-points. Maybe you can have a look there. Cheers!

Comment: @Axel It seems that there are still some problems with my code, I'll try my best to fix it in a few days. Besides,  I gave a straightforward solution in your new post, hope it helps.