# Removing repetitions removes too many points

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to remove repetitive data from an a set of key value pairs. Those repetitions have exactly the same key or the keys can be very close to each other. In those cases I only want to keep the key value pair with the largest value.

The solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280156/remove-duplicate-key-value-pairs-with-tolerance-by-keeping-the-ones-with-largest)

```
ind=-1;
while(~isempty(ind))
  %find the non-max point
  Max=([diff(vals) 0]<0 & [0 -diff(vals)]<0); 
  Nind=1:length(vals);
  Nind(Max)=[];

  %determine the range of points
  Cind=[0 diff(keys)<0.5 & abs(diff(keys)>0.01)];
  Cind(find(Cind)-1)=1;
  vec=1:length(Cind);
  Cind=Cind.*vec;
  Cind(Cind == 0)=[];

  %check through & back
  ind=intersect(Cind,Nind);
  keys(ind)=[];
  vals(ind)=[];
end
```

works for the given set of pairs

```
keys = [1 2 3 3.1 3.15 4 5];
vals = [0.8 1 1.1 1.3 1.2 1 1.1];
```

so when the input looks like

[image: Input plot]

then the output looks like this

[image]

removing the repetitions around `3` and `6`.

However if I apply the same solution to the set

```
keys = [414 414 999 1011 1070 1280 1280 1635 1641 1793 1799 1870 1872 1886 2213 2214 2225 2572 3778 3790 4970];
values = [1.100 1.100 0.316 0.198 0.224 0.555 0.555 0.443 0.374 0.387 0.510 0.446 0.456 0.347 0.224 0.229 0.171 0.175 0.202 0.183 0.147];
```

and accordingly change the threshold to

```
Cind=[0 diff(keys)<13 & abs(diff(keys)>0.01)];
```

then the input looks like

[image: input plot 2]

and the output looks like

[image: output plot 2]

The problem in this case is that too many points are removed. For example in the red circle the largest point in the group is removed and of the three points in the region only one is kept although the distance is well above the set threshold of 13. Also the point at 1635 is removed although all larger values are more then 13 away.

What is my misunderstanding here?

**Edit:** The desired output would be that of those key value pairs where the keys are very close to each other only the one with the largest value would be kept and the other would be removed from both arrays. I indicated those points that should be merged to the largest value in this plot:

[image: Indication of desired output]

**Edit 2:** The desired output array would therefore be:

```
keys = [414 999 1070 1280 1635 1799 1872 1886 2213 2225 2572 3778 4970];
vals = [1.100 0.316 0.224 0.555 0.443 0.510 0.456 0.347 0.224 0.171 0.175 0.202 0.147];
```

Comment: What is the desired output for this pair of keys and values?

Comment: Hi @pkpkpk please see the edit I just made.

Comment: Its easier if you add the desired output for the matrices rather than the plot :)

Comment: Hi @pkpkpk sorry for the inconvenience ;-) I added the desired output array in my last edit. As I did this manually I hope I didn't make any mistakes. The basic idea is that if some pairs are very close (inside a set distance) to each other only the one with largest value should be kept and all other should be removed from the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straightforward, pretty simple strategy, which only contains some if statements and delete one point at a time, but it works anyway.

However, the code following has the complexity of **O(N^2)** and has nothing to do with the vectorization, which will be very time consuming when the input became considerable.

```
%% Input
clc; clear;
keys = [414 414 999 1011 1070 1280 1280 1635 1641 1793 1799 1870 1872 1886 2213 2214 2225 2572 3778 3790 4970];
vals = [1.100 1.100 0.316 0.198 0.224 0.555 0.555 0.443 0.374 0.387 0.510 0.446 0.456 0.347 0.224 0.229 0.171 0.175 0.202 0.183 0.147];

%% Dealing
[len,flag]=deal(13,1);
while flag
  flag=0;
  for ii=2:length(keys)
    if ((keys(ii)-keys(ii-1) > len))
      continue;
    else
      if (vals(ii) > vals(ii-1))
        keys(ii-1)=[];
        vals(ii-1)=[];
      else
        keys(ii)=[];
        vals(ii)=[];
      end
      flag=1;
      break;
    end
  end
end

%% plot
figure(1)
plot(keys,vals)
hold on 
plot(keys,vals,'ro')
for ii=1:length(vals)
  text(keys(ii),vals(ii),num2str(ii))  
end
```

The code will output:

[image]

Comment: Ummm, it's hard to calculate but I believe that the complexity of the code must less than O(N^2).

Comment: Hi Hunter! Thanks for your answer. As the sets in my case only contain 50-100 pairs I don't think the vectorization is that important. Even O(n^2) is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the code will remove two neighboring points, where one is close to a larger value, and the second point is close to the first one being removed, but not the larger value that is kept. The simplest fix (not the prettiest) would be to remove only one element in each iteration of the loop. For example:

```
while true         % changed code
  %find the non-max point
  Max=([diff(vals) 0]<0 & [0 -diff(vals)]<0); 
  Nind=1:length(vals);
  Nind(Max)=[];

  %determine the range of points
  Cind=[0 diff(keys)<13 & abs(diff(keys)>0.01)];
  Cind(find(Cind)-1)=1;
  vec=1:length(Cind);
  Cind=Cind.*vec;
  Cind(Cind == 0)=[];

  %check through & back
  ind=intersect(Cind,Nind);
  if isempty(ind)  % added code
     break         % added code
  end              % added code
  ind=ind(1);      % added code
  keys(ind)=[];
  vals(ind)=[];
end
```

PS: Why did you add `& abs(diff(keys)>0.01)` to the previous answer? It causes very close points to be kept, which is not what your intention is according to your description of the problem.

Comment: Hi Cris! Thanks for your answer. There seems to be a small issue with it as the output array for the test set is `[414 1011 1070 1280 1641 1799 1872 1886 2225 2572 3778 4970]` so it seems to keep the wrong key value pairs in some cases.